# KendoMobile scrollview problems with transition animations

Tags: kendo-ui, scrollview, kendo-mobile

I'm currently developping a WebApp with KendoMobile.

I have use a scrollView to display an informations bar like you can see on the picture below :

[image]

The problem comes when I click on a marker. 
I wrote a function that change the page of the scrollview to match the marker I clicked.

Here is the code of the method :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerObj, 'click', function() {
    var page = fournisseursArrayIndexOf(markerObj.data["ID"]);
    console.log("marker title : " + markerObj.title + " / footer page : " + page);

    var footer  = $("#footer").data("kendoMobileScrollView");
    var curpage = footer.page;

    markers[curpage].setIcon(normalImg);
    markerObj.setIcon(selectedImg);

    footer.scrollTo(page);
    //map.panTo(markerObj.position);
});
```

I read [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/scrollview#methods-scrollTo) that if I use the scrollTo method with a single parameter (the page index that I want to show), there will be a transition animation by default.
But nothing happens, I mean the page do change, but there no animation.

I searched on Kendo forum but the only topic I found is [this one](http://www.telerik.com/forums/scrollto-without-animation) but it's the exact opposite of what I want : He want to delete the animation when I want to have it.
But that helps me kind of because it mean that having an animation is possible.

Does someone know the solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved ! Sort of...

I tested many things by modifying the code of the KendoMobileScrollView and I found that the animation that is supposed to be displayed when you call the scrollTo method doesn't work with scrollview filled with a template.

So if someone encounter the same problem : you'll have to write a loop that will create the pages of your scrollview and insert it in the DOM.

Looks like this :

```
var htmlToAppen = "<div data-role=\"page\>"";

for(var i = 0 ; i < yourObjectsArray.length ; i++) {
    var curObj = yourObjectsArray[i];

    htmlToAppen += "<div> objName : " + curObj.name + "</div>";

    htmlToAppen += "</div>"; 
}

$("#yourScrollDiv").append(htmlToAppend);
$("#yourScrollDiv").kendoMobileScrollView({
    enablePager : false
});
```